# MATLAB scatter3, plot3 speed discrepencies

Tags: matlab, plot, timing, scatter-plot

This is about how MATLAB can take very different times to plot the same thing — and why.

I generate 10000 points in 3D space:

```
X = rand(10000, 1);
Y = rand(10000, 1);
Z = rand(10000, 1);
```

I then used one of four different methods to plot this, to create a plot like so:

[image]

I closed all figures and cleared the workspace between each run to try to ensure fairness.

**Bulk plotting using scatter3:**

```
>> tic; scatter3(X, Y, Z); drawnow; toc
Elapsed time is 0.815450 seconds.
```

**Individual plotting using scatter3:**

```
>> tic; hold on;
for i = 1:10000
    scatter3(X(i), Y(i), Z(i), 'b');
end
hold off; drawnow; toc
Elapsed time is 51.469547 seconds.
```

**Bulk plotting using plot3:**

```
>> tic; plot3(X, Y, Z, 'o'); drawnow; toc
Elapsed time is 0.153480 seconds.
```

**Individual plotting using plot3:**

```
>> tic; hold on
for i = 1:10000
    plot3(X(i), Y(i), Z(i), 'o');
end
drawnow; toc
Elapsed time is 5.854662 seconds.
```

What is it that MATLAB does behind the scenes in the 'longer' routines to take so long? What are the advantages and disadvantages of using each method?

**Edit:**
Thanks to advice from Ben Voigt (see answers), I have included `drawnow` commands in the timing — but this has made little difference to the times.

Comment: Made little difference?  The time for bulk `plot3` increased by three orders of magnitude!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference between the time required to run `scatter3` and `plot3` comes from the fact that `plot3` is compiled, while `scatter3` is interpreted (as you'll see when you edit the functions). If `scatter3` was compiled as well, the speed difference would be small.

The main difference between the time required to plot in a loop versus plotting in one go is that you add the handle to the plot as a child to the axes (have a look at the output of `get(gca,'Children')`), and you're thus growing a complicated array inside a loop, which we all know to be slow. Furthermore, you're calling several functions often instead of just once and incur thus calls from the function overhead.

Recalculation of axes limits aren't an issue here. If you run

```
for i = 1:10000
    plot3(X(i), Y(i), Z(i), 'o');
    drawnow;
end
```

which forces Matlab to update the figure at every iteration (and which is A LOT slower), you'll see that the axes limits don't change at all (since the default axes limits are 0 and 1). However, even if the axes limits started out differently, it wouldn't take many iterations for them to converge with these data. Compare with omitting the `hold on`, which makes plotting take longer, because axes are recalculated at every step.

Why have these different functions? `scatter3` allows you to plot points with different marker sizes, and colors under a single handle, while you'd need a loop and get a handle for each point using `plot3`, which is not only costly in terms of speed, but also in terms of memory. However, if you need to interact with different points (or groups of points) individually - maybe you want to add a separate legend entry for each, maybe you want to be able to turn them on and off separately etc - using `plot3` in a loop may be the best (though slow) solution.

Comment: Thanks, this really cleared up the issues about speed differences, particularly wrt what's happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 6):

For a faster approach, consider this third option (directly uses the low-level function LINE):

```
line([X,X], [Y,Y], [Z,Z], 'LineStyle','none', 'Marker','o', 'Color','b')
view(3)
```

---

Here are some articles discussing plotting performance issues:

- [Performance: scatter vs. line](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/performance-scatter-vs-line/)
- [Plot performance](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-performance/)

Comment: In addition to the articles you mentioned on UndocumentedMatlab.com, note the following article that explains that the scatter function works unexpectedly when requested to plot 100+ data points: http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/blog/undocumented-scatter-plot-behavior/

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you wanted control over the color of each point, bulk scatter would be faster, because you'd need to call plot separately.

Also, I'm not sure your timing information is accurate because you haven't called `drawnow`, so the actual drawing could take place after `toc`.

In summary:

- `plot3` is fastest because it draws the same marker at many different locations
- `scatter3` draws many different markers, since size and color of the marker (are allowed to) vary with each point
- calling in a loop is really slow, because argument parsing and so forth have to take place repeatedly, in addition as points are added to the plot the axes have to be recalculated

Comment: That's very interesting - so does MATLAB plot things at a random time after they've been called? Again, why? What does MATLAB do in its code to cause this?

Comment: Pretty much ALL gui programs plot things only when they receive a paint request from the operating system.  This is actually a VERY good thing.  I notice that you're using automatic axes, thus the `hold on` version calculates one axis scale for the first point, a new axis scale when you add the next point, and adjusts the axes again every time you add a new point that doesn't fall within the previously plotted points.  If it rendered immediately, it'd have to draw the axis, ticks, titles, etc hundreds of times instead of just once.  Or the figure window could be minimized or covered.

Comment: Aha. This is very good to know. So the axes are resized for each new point. I can see that this would be time consuming, thanks.

Comment: Of course the bulk version simply finds the `min()` and `max()` of `X`, `Y`, and `Z` and sets the axes once.  It's the `hold on` version, which you called individual plotting, that has to recalculate axes repeatedly.